# Maximum likelihood when the data is a parametric function of fixed data parameterized by the parameter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Normally in maximum likelihood estimation, we have fixed data $x$, and have a parametric family of models governed by $\theta$. The $\theta$ chosen is the one that maximizes $p(x \mid \theta)$.

But my situation is, that there is fixed data $x$ that I have observed. I would ideally like to maximize the likelihood $p(x \mid \theta)$, but that is too complicated. However, it is easy to know the likelihood of some known function, parametrized by $\theta$, of $x$, $g_\theta(x)$, that I know. What I can do is, for each $\theta$, compute $g_\theta(x)$, and then look at $p_{g_\theta(x) \mid \theta}(g_\theta(x) \mid \theta)$.

So, instead of maximizing $p(x \mid \theta)$, can I instead maximize $p(g_\theta(x) \mid \theta)$? Is this a well-defined thing to do? Has it been done before? Will it work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If one observes $y=g_\theta(x)$ when $x\sim p(x|\theta)$, the ensuing density of $y$ need be taken as the likelihood.

Comment: @Xi'an can you please explain what you mean by this idea? I'm not sure I quite follow. Thank you!